# Wicket Dropdownchoice can not change the selected value

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

I have two DropDownChoice component of category1 and category2. I want change the list of category2 when changing the selected value of category1. But the changed value of category1 always keep the init value when the method of category1.getModelObject() invoked.

```
private void addCategoryChoice(Form form) {
    List<Category1> category1List = category1Impl.listProduct();

    ChoiceRenderer renderer1=new  ChoiceRenderer<Category1>() {
        @Override
        public Object getDisplayValue(Category1 value) {
            return value.getName();
        }
    };
    DropDownChoice<Category1> category1 = new DropDownChoice<Category1>("category1",
          new Model<Category1>(category1List.get(1)) , category1List,renderer1);

    category2List = category2Imple.listByCategory1Id(category1.getModelObject().getId());
    ChoiceRenderer renderer2=new  ChoiceRenderer<Category2>() {
        @Override
        public Object getDisplayValue(Category2 value) {
            return value.getName();
        }
    };
    DropDownChoice<Category2> category2 = new DropDownChoice("category2",category2List,renderer2);
    form.add(category2);

    category1.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("change") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            category2List.clear();

            int id=category1.getModelObject().getId();
            category2List.addAll(category2Imple.listByCategory1Id(Integer.valueOf(id)));
            category2.setChoices(category2List);
        }
    });
    form.add(category1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AjaxEventBehavior doesn't update component model. You should use OnChangeAjaxBehavior instead.

Comment: The problem is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I would think this would rather be done with a simple AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior on the "change" event. Any specific reason you picket OnChangeAjaxBehavior?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS OnChangeAjaxBehavior is a smarter version of AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. It uses both `change` and `input` for TextField and TextArea.